# Anonymous Access to Samba Server (not share)

Tags: samba

I'm pulling my hair out here, so I really hope someone can help.

**Background**

I *had* a Volumio Debian server and I set up the media files such that I could browse the server anonymously thus: \\192.168.50.230. I was ablw to do this from Windows (with AllowInsecureGuestAuth = 1) and Android. Both allowed me to enter only the server name (\\192.168.50.230) and it would list all the shares. I recall it was a bit fiddly but it worked.
2 days ago I reinstalled Volumio. NOTE: I reinstalled the *same* version on the same hardware. The client devices (Windows and Android) are the same.

**Problem**

Whilist I can set up guest access to the *share*, I am now prompted for a password when accessing the samba *server*: \\192.168.50.230. Interestingly, if I enter *any* user name and password, it lets me in, so I know I am going in as nobody. (Indeed, I have confirmed this by creating new files and seeing who owns it. E.g. if I do "map to guest = testuser" then testuser is the owner, so that bit's working.)

**Things Tried**

I have read the smb.conf documentation here https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/smb.conf.5.html. (NOTE: Where the documentation states the default value, in general I have omitted that setting. Nevertheless, I have in some testing adding in the value, but it makes no difference. An example: security = user which is the default anyway.)

This person had the same issue: https://samba.samba.narkive.com/kSLUDcBR/behavior-of-deprecated-share-security-with-user-security Their solution was using "map to guest = bad password" instead of "bad user". However, it makes no difference. Indeed, according to the doc, if the user I am trying to log in as *doesn't* exist [which they don't] it'll map the user onto the guest user in both case. My testing confirms this.)

This is similar: https://serverfault.com/questions/470650/samba-configuration-for-public-shares but is focusses on *shares* but my focus is before we even get to shares.

This again is about the share: [https://askubuntu.com/questions/781963/simple-samba-share-no-password>](https://askubuntu.com/questions/781963/simple-samba-share-no-password%3E) . As before, if I authenticate at the samba server with anything, it allows access  to the share anyway, so not really relevant. (Or, more accurately, once I am authenticated on the server, the guest share side of things works fine.)

This post has a share-based issue https://superuser.com/questions/1315008/minimal-fully-guest-browsable-samba-share and I did try setting the netbios name to the hostname, but that did not work.

This is almost exactly the issue I'm having: https://askubuntu.com/questions/258284/setting-up-an-anonymous-public-samba-share-to-be-accessed-via-windows-7-and-xbmc albeit it it's about XBMC (Kodi). I tried all the idea there but no luck.

**Requirement**

What I'd like is to get back to being able to browse the samba server anonymously so that it lists the shares before I try to access the shares. If only I'd backed up my smb.conf! What I do remember is is was *very* simple - only maybe 10 lines line. I just cannot find the magic glue to fix it.

**Current smb.conf**

The current one is actually back to the default. But really, there is no "current" one as I'd tried what feels like everything. (Obviously it isn't "everything" otherwise it would work!) However, here's one that does *not* work:

```
[global]
    # Stop the printing noise in the logs
    load printers = no
    printing = bsd
    printcap name = /dev/null
    disable spoolss = yes

    # Logging
    log file = /var/log/samba.log

    # Anonymous
    map to guest = Bad User
    guest account = root
    usershare allow guests = yes

[child]
    path = /parent/child
    read only = no
    create mask = 0777
    guest ok = yes
```

(Yes, yes, I know: the mapping of guest to root is bad for security but this wifi only has one user: me. I'm keen that that does not become a distraction to the main question.)

**Thoughts**

I have also tried very loose file system permissions such as 777 on everything. However, I do not think that this is relevant. Why? Because it only looks at the file system when it wants to access a share. But, my problme occurs before I have even decided which share to look at. So, if the problem is in thre samba config, it can only be in the [default] section.

I am also wondering if it relates to something outside of smb.conf such as smbpasswd.

**Distro Info**

PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="8"
VERSION="8 (jessie)"
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
Linux volumio 4.19.118-v7l+ #1311 SMP Mon Apr 27 14:26:42 BST 2020 armv7l GNU/Linux